How to install an old Ubuntu signed kernel?
I'm encountering a lot of errors and malfunctions since I upgraded to Ubuntu 24.10 whereas everything was working fine back on 24.04.
I have problems regarding bluetooth and laptop not recovering from sleep mode (black screen so I need to force shutdown).
After browsing the web and tried for several settings changes I saw a lot of threads that advised me to downgrade the kernel.
I tried to do it with mainline kernels utility but they are non signed kernels and I don't want to disable secure boot.
I search for ubuntu signed kernel and found a release page from this ppa.
I tried to download and install deb package directly using sudo dpkg -i linux-image-uc-6.8.0-49-generic_6.8.0-49.49_amd64.deb but without luck.
They are not built like mainline kernels that consist on 4 .deb packages.
First, is it a good idea to install former ubuntu signed kernel on a new ubuntu release ?
If yes, should I install it by adding the ppa or by manually downloading the wanted files.
In both cases can you provide me with the steps to do so ?
Regards,

In Ubuntu, use browser to navigate to > http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/ Scroll to the bottom of the list; choose your kernel. Download the following files (xxxxxx will be replaced with numbers indicating the kernel version. Assuming you have a 64bit OS):
linux-headers-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb

linux-headers-xxxxxx_all.deb

linux-image-xxxxxx-generic-xxxxxx_amd64.deb

Move all these files to a folder. cd into it. Install all these packages by running
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

Choose new kernel from grub menu.

As I said in my post: mainline kernels are not signed. You've given the same exact answer an IA gave to me. I doubt you've really read the question and I know how to prompt by myself.

did you try to check if in the official site of linux is?
